# Y coordinate of UIView is changing after viewDidAppear called

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview

In my App UIView of ViewController Y position is changing after viewDidAppear method invoked.

I am not having any navigation controller for ParentView. Check below code
how I am presenting SecondViewController from FirstViewController.

```
TGRImageViewController *viewController = [[TGRImageViewController alloc] initWithImage:self.userImage.image];

viewController.transitioningDelegate = self;
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question or explained how and when it's changing

Comment: Do you have AutoLayout turned on for this view/Storyboard ?  If so, that'd explain it.

Comment: AutoLayout is off. I am using AutoReszingMasks only.

Comment: I am unable to post the screens since I have less than 10 reputation.